# Each text box should be in a new row in the panel

Tags: html, css

I have created a panel for my webpage. The panel contains two text boxes with labels. As of now the two text boxes are in the same row. I want each text box to be in a different row. How should I do it? I have tried including the `<br>` inside the panel.

```
<html>

<head>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="C:Users/annap/code/interview-scheduler/qxf2_scheduler/static/css/qxf2_scheduler.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .navbar img {
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            position: relative;
            top: -12px;

        }

        .navbar h1 {
            top: 18px;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: brown;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navbar {
            min-height: 80px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <h1>My heading</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Thankyou for applying with us. To schedule an interview please fill the below details </p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Enter your name</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input id="candidate-name" name="candidate-name" type="text" placeholder="John"
                        class="form-control input-md" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Enter your email</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input id="candidate-email" name="candidate-email" type="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
                        class="form-control input-md" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="save"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="btn btn-success show-modal" type='submit' id='submit' value='Go for schedule'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

I can see two text boxes with name and email coming in one row.
What I have tried is

```
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

by referring to this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_stacked_form,
but its not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just run your code and they are just as the link you provided is. I do not see any issues. which browser are you on? can you share a screenshot of what you have and what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you meaning... can you please let me know what do you mean saying `As of now the two text boxes are in the same row. I want each text box should be in each row. How should I do it`? I can see they different rows

Comment: This is happening because of inappropriate use of bootstrap grid system in your code by providing col-md-3 the input components parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this? 
[image]

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Enter your name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="candidate-name" name="candidate-name" type="text" placeholder="John"
                            class="form-control input-md" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Enter your email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="candidate-email" name="candidate-email" type="email"
                            placeholder="johndoe@example.com" class="form-control input-md" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Or Like this:

[image]

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Thankyou for applying with us. To schedule an interview please fill the below details </p>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-3 clo-xs-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="formGroupExampleInput" for="formGroupExampleInput">Enter your name</label>
                    <input id="afm" class="form-control custom-input-text"  placeholder="">             
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-4 clo-xs-3" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="formGroupExampleInput" for="formGroupExampleInput">Enter your email</label>
                    <input id="afm" class="form-control custom-input-text"  placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,It's working now. I am not sure what changes you have done. Can you tell me?

Comment: Great!Which one you mean? i gave 2 solutions because i wasnt sure

Comment: On one row i have 2 columns, one for label and one for input!For the second label and input i'm using new row

Answer (score 0):

Issue is using `col` remove that `col` form `label` and `input` will fix the issue

```css
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar img {
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            position: relative;
            top: -12px;

        }

        .navbar h1 {
            top: 18px;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: brown;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navbar {
            min-height: 80px;
        }
```

```html
<head>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="C:Users/annap/code/interview-scheduler/qxf2_scheduler/static/css/qxf2_scheduler.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <h1>My heading</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Thankyou for applying with us. To schedule an interview please fill the below details </p>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <label class=" control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Enter your name</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input id="candidate-name" name="candidate-name" type="text" placeholder="John"
                        class="form-control input-md" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class=" control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Enter your email</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input id="candidate-email" name="candidate-email" type="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
                        class="form-control input-md" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class=" control-label" for="save"></label>
                <div class="">
                    <input class="btn btn-success show-modal" type='submit' id='submit' value='Go for schedule'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



</body>
```